# How to save previous and next element of an array in session storage in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, session-storage

I am creating an automated prev/next linking between subpages. On the main page, there are several groups of links pointing to these subpages. I need to set up the prev/next navigation within a certain group in a proper order. 
I don't know anything back-end based, so I have to do this with jQuery.

My idea is:

1. Push every link from certain group to an array and place the array in the sessionStorage
2. Save the link that've been clicked in the sessionStorage
3. Check if there is a match and find links before and after the link that is clicked
4. Create navigation based on findings

Everything was fine until now. Rigth now, I'm stuck. Pushing to array and saving in sessionStorage works good, the same with saving the clicked link. But, for some reason, I cannot make it work to find the previous and next link in an array. This is my code:

```
var root_url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host
var hrefs_tiles = new Array();

jQuery('.wp-tiles-grid').each(function(){
    var current_tiles = jQuery(this);
    current_tiles.on('click',function(){
        current_tiles.find('a').each(function(){
            var attr_href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
            hrefs_tiles.push(root_url + attr_href);
            sessionStorage.setItem("hrefs_tiles", hrefs_tiles);
        });
    });
});
jQuery('.wp-tiles-grid a').on('click',function(){
    var current_href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    var current_link = root_url +current_href
    sessionStorage.setItem("link", current_link);
    hrefs_tiles.forEach(function(item){
        var link = sessionStorage.getItem("link");
        if (item == current_link){
            var next = hrefs_tiles[(jQuery.inArray(current_link, hrefs_tiles) + 1) % hrefs_tiles.length];
            var prev = hrefs_tiles[(jQuery.inArray(current_link, hrefs_tiles) - 1 + hrefs_tiles.length) % hrefs_tiles.length];
            sessionStorage.setItem("prev", prev);
            sessionStorage.setItem("next", next);
        };
    });
});
```

I would be very grateful for your help!

Comment: Have you looked at the browser history API? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API or you need that sessionStorage?

Comment: I need sessionStorage for you can get on this subpages from the other way, so going back in history is not a solution right now :/. Anyway, with the history thing you cannot go to the next subpage, you will be able to see only the ones you have visited